# Adding Custom HTTP Response Headers in IIS Failed

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I've had an .NET framework deployed website for sometime that runs on an ec2 using IIS.
As part of the deployment, we add a response header so we know what version of the code the call is using.

This has worked until I recently, when I added a WCF service reference to the code and now I get this:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anbs9.jpg)

All other changes are very minor so I assume its something to do with the WCF service.
Other than this, the service is running fine and no obvious errors from that end.

The changes to the web.config can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBktY.jpg). All these code changes were automatically added when adding the connected service in Visual Studio

Comment: I think this may have nothing to do with WCF. Adding a WCF service reference just generates a proxy class and will not have any other impact on the program. Even without adding a WCF service reference, we can call the service through the channel factory. I suggest you try to add a new site to see if you can add custom http response headers.

Comment: Hi @DingPeng, There are 4 other sites (same code just previous version) currently running on the same IIS and they all have the Custom Headers set correctly. I can also restore the code to the previous version and can set the Headers. So my assumption is something in the latest commit as nothing was changed in the deploy

Comment: Can you add Custom HTTP Response Headers if you delete the content in web.config?